# Where do custom components go in Next.js 13 file structure?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

With this version, are you meant to create a Components/ folder inside the app folder? Or can I add new components anywhere in the file structure?

I currently have a components/ folder nested inside the app/ which seems to work fine. But I'm not sure if this can cause issues or if there is a better approach.

Can each "page" get it's own components/ folder?

Answer (score 1):

As in the example [Mahesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4640892/mahesh-more) gave, you cannot just create a components dir inside the app router, however you can create a (components) dir without making the comps create new routes!
[docs src](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure#route-groups-and-private-folders)
so it'd be like this:[image]

Comment: In your case, wouldn't it be better to name it `_components`? `(components)` only groups them without adding the folder prefix to the route, whereas _components is a private folder (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/colocation#private-folders).

You could also add a folder ./components (outside of ./app).

Comment: @JorisKok
Yes you are right, actually it goes outside the app/ dir, that'd be the equivalent of making a components/ dir inside pages/
The recommended folder structure is to select yes to create a src/ dir and put components/ there (I found it in several tutorials and my boss told me)

Answer (score 1):

I found and also recommend to you this awesome [folder structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76506760/4457077) to use in  Next.js 13.4 or newer version with new App router, hope you like it!

[image: folder structure for next.js 13.4]

Answer (score 1):

As for nextJS 13, hence the app pages folder is specifically for routes as per the docs (https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure#route-groups-and-private-folders), it is recommended to use a separate directory for the components, I get your point in wanting to organise your folder structure, as for me i do it right now in this way:
[own component structure in nextjs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsRgI.png)

and if you need/want it to be more organised in terms of only let specific components for specific pages, then i could also recommend to you the following structure (I would use if I needed to get my codebase more organised):

```
--- app
    |- somePage
       -- page.tsx

--- components
    |- somePage
     -- CustomComponentA
        -- CustomComponentA.tsx
    |- CustomComponentB
       -- CustomComponentA.tsx
      ..etc.
```

Answer (score -2):

In NextJS anything you keep inside the `pages` folder is considered a page or subpage, lets's say you have created the `components` folder inside one of the `pages` folders like below. Then you can access the components inside this folder as pages, so you can access this component with the below URL.

`https://baseUrl/admin/components/componentName`

[image]

So in NextJs, everything we put inside the pages folder is considered an individual page. If you want a separate `space/folder` for components you can create feature-level components outside the page folder like below.

[image]

Now components added in this feature folder are not accessible as a page and you can reuse these components as you want.

I hope this answered your question. Happy coding!

Comment: The question specified that the file structure in question regarded NextJS version 13, which uses the `app` structure in place of the older `pages` structure, this is why your answer is getting downvoted.