# NextJS 13 folder structure best practice

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13

I'm learning to use NextJS and I'm using the latest version with App Router, I'm currently stuck on how to do routing, such as where to put the register and login pages, and its' folder structure in general, where I put components and how to group other related components together, can you shed light on this topic, and please make it as simple as possible and maybe give some examples because I'm still learning, any help would be much appreciated, thankyou !

Comment: Reference this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53854104/is-this-next-js-folder-structure-recommended

Comment: It's personal preference, but a common pattern is a `components/` folder at the same level as `pages/` (pages is used for routing). That structure is implied here https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts

Answer (score 115):

I think reading this section in Next docs helps you organize the project folders:

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/colocation

I tried with many different structures and I finally chose this one:

1. Everything (all folders and files) will be in the `/app` directory because the `/app` directory accepts colocation and it’s different from `/pages` directory which was only for routing purposes. In this way `/app` directory can be assumed the new `/src` directory.
2. All the non-routes folders will be Private Folders by prefixing their name with an underscore (as stated in the link above). This tells the Next router that this folder is not part of the routes. (e.g. `_components`, `_libs`, ...)
3. To this point we established that every folder with underscore `_` is not route and other folders without it are a part of the routing system (although having a `page.tsx` or `page.js` file in the folder is another condition for being a part of the routing system), but I used another Next 13 feature and it is Route Groups (as stated in the link above). It is wrapping a folder name in parenthesis, so that it shows the folder is for organizational purposes (grouping folders) and should not be included in the route’s URL path, e.g. (routes).

With these principles, I have all my required folders in `/app` directory, and with Route Groups all my routes are grouped in a `(routes)` folder, and with Private Folders by prefixing non-route folders with underscore, everything is isolated.

The image below is the summary of all the points above.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrJoY.png]

Hope the link and my way of organizing project folders help you.

Comment: I liked this approach. but I don't know if the feature of some file with specific name can complicate this. For example, "error.tsx" or "page.tsx" outside of (routes)

Comment: @FranciscoOssian As I mentioned in second point, all private folders (prefixed with underscore) are excluded from route system even if they have "error.tsx" or "page.tsx". The only place that can cause problem is the root of /app directory which these kinds of filenames should be avoided. It is just one place and easy to avoid IMHO.

Comment: I'm always confused what people mean by "component". I know generic reusable things like buttons, modals, etc. are components, but what about specific things? Say you have a route `/app/(routes)/login/page.tsx`. If you have a "component" that is specific to the login page, would it make sense to keep it in the login route folder? Or would you move that to the component directory and only keep page.tsx an layout.tsx files in the (routes) folder.

Comment: This make sense IF you're NOT using the `src` folder.  If you use the `src` folder, go with @Yilmaz's answer below

Comment: @Joe if a component is only used inside a specific page or other component, I add it to a folder called components inside the folder for that specific page/component. If it is used in other places, I will move it out to a general components folder.

Comment: What would be the recommendation for structuring custom styles for each page?

Comment: it would be worth mentioning parallel routing with @ in nextjs along with this folder structure, for better maintanance of component level loading and error handling for complicated dashboards 

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/parallel-routes

Comment: Hi, do you mind helping me out with my question please.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78139260/axios-intereptor-implementation-with-next-js-and-jwt

Answer (score 69):

[image]

Some keep the `components` inside the app but I keep them outside to tell other engineers that `app` directory includes only page components. if you put too many folders in app directory, then it will be hard for other engineers to understand what routes actually exist inside our application. if you have this structure in `app` directory it will be clear which routes exist:

[image]

If you have similar routes that have shared layouts you can use `()` syntax inside `app` directory. For example

[image]

Inside `auth` folder you can have `login` and `signup` pages with the shared layout.

Inside the components folder, you can create sub-folders for `providers`, `ui`, or `shared` components.

Comment: I want try to implement this but what is pages folder for ?  
What if we create component only on one page not shared for another page where is should put it ?

Comment: In early versions, pages folder existed too when you created a new project

Comment: You have both "pages" and "app" folders. What do you keep in "pages" folder?

Comment: @AmirH.Bagheri pages should have “api” folder, and route files.

Comment: @Yilmaz Hi, can you please help me out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78139260/axios-intereptor-implementation-with-next-js-and-jwt

Answer (score 15):

In version 13, Next.js introduced a new **App Router** built on **React Server Components**. Means whatever component you will place under the app directory will by default work as a **server component**.
I will suggest to place components inside the `/app` directory if you wanna **render** the components on **server side**. You can also place the components inside the folders of any page.

```
/app
  /components
  /dashboard
    customComponent.tsx
    page.tsx
  layout.tsx
  page.tsx
```

For getting more of the File Conventions read this article:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing

Comment: The components will be rendered on server even if the components folder was created outside of app folder

Comment: Yeah, i just read about it, thanks for adding this.

Comment: @GilbishKosma is there any advantage to using server-side rendering? Wouldn't having them on the client side be faster?

Comment: @Victor the advantage depends on whats your priority. If priority is SEO , fast initial rendering then we can go with SSR. CSR will be better if the webpage is highly interactive, in cases when content change frequently without full page reload. Most B2B apps benefit from using CSR, ex. a CMS portal, inventory management app ,etc. Basically use CSR for which you don't want the data to be available in google search. One more point if In Next js if you are using event handlers in any component, then that component will require "use client" as it will render it in Client side.

Comment: Worth noting that [directories can be ignored for routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure#route-groups-and-private-folders) by prefixing the directory name with an underscore (e.g., `app/_components`).

Answer (score 0):

you can use various routing in latest App router version and even customise the routing to use your own customised routing.

Default Routing with Next.js App Router:
for creating a page,you can directly create a folder with page name inside the folder
for example about page,create about folder, create page.jsx(inside about folder,act as the index page for about i.e. can be accessed by URL/about)
App
/about
page.jsx

2.) To implement custom routing

you can add in next-config

```
async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/old-route',
        destination: '/new-route',
      },
      // Add more custom routes as needed
    ];
```

I have researched over the directory structure too when i started
For Best Practices ,i directly create the pages inside the App directory.like
all/products/page.jsx or app/about/page.jsx

for admin ui , i use app/admin/pagenameofadmin/page.jsx
app/admin/page.tsx(admin home page)

for all other components use components folder,and create subfolders in components to find components easily

layout  - for common and repetitive components like header/footer/sidebar
auth -   for login signup related components
admin - for admin ui components
pagename - for page specific component

can also create for folder for specific content type if you want to keep everything organised at next level, i recommend to use it for complex projects only
product - for products realted components

keep apis inside app/utils folder.

Comment: could you please describe more about this :::: can also create for folder for specific content type if you want to keep everything organised at next level, i recommend to use it for complex projects only product - for products realted components

keep apis inside app/utils folder.

Comment: Instead of making different components for each type of content on different pages, you can save time and effort by reusing the same components for similar content types. For example, if you have products, categories, and blogs in your application, instead of creating separate components for each page (like a "productpage"folder for component), you can organize them in folders named after the content type (like a "product" folder). This way, you can use the same components across different pages, making it easier to manage and update your application.

Answer (score -21):

A simple folder structure example that you can follow:

1. Create a pages directory in the root of your Next.js project. This is where you'll place your page components that correspond to different routes.
2. Create an auth directory to group all authentication-related pages together inside the pages directory. For example:

   ```
    pages/
      auth/
        login.js
        register.js
   ```
3. In the login.js and register.js files, you can create your login and register page components. For example:

   ```
    // pages/auth/login.js
    const LoginPage = () => {
        return <div>Login page</div>;
    };

    export default LoginPage;
   ```
4. Next Create a page register.js:

   ```
    // pages/auth/register.js
    const RegisterPage = () => {
        return <div>Register page</div>;
    };

    export default RegisterPage;
   ```
5. To set up routing, you can use Next.js' built-in App component and Router from the next/router module. Here's an example of how you can configure your routes:

   ```
        // pages/_app.js
    import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

    const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
        const router = useRouter();

        // Check if the current route is an authentication route
        const isAuthRoute = router.pathname.startsWith('/auth');

        // You can perform any common layout or logic for all pages here

        // Wrap authentication pages with a layout or authentication-specific logic
        if (isAuthRoute) {
            // Add authentication layout or logic here if needed

            // For example, you can add a common navigation component
            // or apply styles specific to authentication pages

            return <Component {...pageProps} />;
        }

        // For non-authentication pages, you can apply a different layout or logic
        // or simply return the component as it is
        return <Component {...pageProps} />;
    };

    export default MyApp;
   ```

In the above example, we use the _app.js file to configure the layout or logic for different pages based on the route. We check if the current route is an authentication route (in this case, starting with /auth), and based on that, we can apply a specific layout or logic.

Note: You can further customize the layout and logic in the MyApp component based on your specific requirements.

With this setup, you can access your login page at /auth/login and the register page at /auth/register.

Remember to run npm run dev or yarn dev to start the Next.js development server and navigate to the appropriate routes to see the pages in action.

This is a basic example to help you get started with the folder structure and routing in Next.js. You can modify and expand it based on your project's needs.

Comment: This looks like ChatGPT

Comment: Since it is not addressing the new routing in nextjs 13.4 then it does look like it had some chatGPT help, yes