# Axios intereptor implementation with Next.js and JWT

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, axios

i currently have a nodejs backend and a next js frontend.

when the user logins, the backend sends the frontend 2 tokens an access token and a refresh token.

i am building an interceptor to attach the access token with every request being sent from my frontend.

since nextjs is both client side and server side, i developed 2 proxy middlewares, 1 for client side requests and 1 for server side requests

BACKEND
auth.service.js

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

//Use different secret keys for access and refresh tokens to enhance security.

function generateAccessToken(user) {
    const payload = { userId: user.id };
    const token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, { expiresIn: '2m' }); // Short expiration for access token //here recommended 15m
    return token;
  }
  
function generateRefreshToken(user) {
    const payload = { userId: user.id };
    const token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, { expiresIn: '7d' }); // Longer expiration for refresh token
    return token;
  }

module.exports = {
  generateAccessToken,
  generateRefreshToken,
};
```

FRONTEND

axios interceptor

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {getRefreshToken,
  getAccessToken,
  storeToken,storeAccessTokenInCookies} from './storage';
import { parseCookies, setCookie } from 'nookies';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'
import {refreshTokenHook} from '../hooks/useRefresh'; // Adjust the import path as needed

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL:process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL,
    // headers: {
    //   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    // },
    // withCredentials: true, // to send cookie
});

const refreshToken = async () => {
      try {
        // console.log('refresh token 1')
        // const refreshToken=Cookies.get("refreshToken");
        // console.log("REFRESH TOKEN",refreshToken)
        // const response = await axios.post('/api/proxy/token/refresh/');
        // console.log('refreshToken response response',response)
        // const tokens = response.data;
        // storeAccessTokenInCookies(tokens.access)
        // // storeToken(tokens);
        // return tokens.access;

        console.log('Attempting to refresh token');
        const newAccessToken = await refreshTokenHook();
        console.log('New access token obtained:', newAccessToken);
        return newAccessToken;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error refreshing token:', error);
        throw error; // Throw error to handle it appropriately where refreshToken is called
    }
};

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
  // console.log('axios interceptor config',config)
  const customConfig = config.config || {};
  console.log('axios interceptor custom config isServerSide',customConfig.isServerSide)
//   const isServerSide = config.config?.isServerSide;

  if (!config.url.includes('/token')) {
  if (customConfig.isServerSide&&typeof window === "undefined") {
    console.log('SERVER SIDE REQUEST')
    // Access the req object from the nested config
    const { req } = customConfig;
    // Your logic to extract and set the token based on req.cookies or another method
    const cookies = parseCookies({ req });
    const accessToken = cookies['accessToken'];

    if (accessToken) {
      console.log('ACCESSTOKENZ server',accessToken)
        config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
    }
} 
// else {
//   console.log('CLIENT SIDE REQUEST')
//   console.log('Cookies available:', Cookies.get())
//     // Client-side: Use a client-side method to get the token, if applicable
//     // const accessToken =  Cookies.get('accessToken');
//     const accessToken = Cookies.get('accessToken'); // Using js-cookie for simplicity
//     console.log('ACCESSTOKENZ client 1', accessToken);

//     if (accessToken) {
//       console.log('ACCESSTOKENZ client 2',accessToken)
//       config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
//     }

// }
  } else{
    console.log('axios interceptor config url',config.url)
    console.log('Accessing /token route, skipping Authorization header.');
  }
  
  return config;
}, error => Promise.reject(error));

let isRefreshing = false;
let failedQueue = [];

const processQueue = (error, token = null) => {
  failedQueue.forEach(prom => {
    if (error) {
      prom.reject(error);
    } else {
      prom.resolve(token);
    }
  });

  failedQueue = [];
};

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    response => response,
    async (error) => {
      console.log('ERRORRRR',error)
      if (!error.response) {
        // Handle errors without a response (e.g., network issues)
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
  
      const { config, response: { status } } = error;
      const originalRequest = config;
      console.log('STATUSSSS',status)
      if (status === 401||status === 403 && !originalRequest._retry) {
        if (isRefreshing) {
          try {
            const token = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              failedQueue.push({ resolve, reject });
            });
            originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
            return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
          } catch (err) {
            return Promise.reject(err);
          }
        }
  
        originalRequest._retry = true;
        isRefreshing = true;
  
        try {
          console.log('TRYING REFRESH MECHANISM')
          const token = await refreshToken();
          axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
          originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
          processQueue(null, token);
          return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
        } catch (err) {
          processQueue(err, null);
          return Promise.reject(err);
        } finally {
          isRefreshing = false;
        }
      }
  
      // For other status codes, just return the error
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );
  

export default axiosInstance;
```

middleware for server side request

```
// utils/proxyRequest.js
import axiosInstance from './axiosInstance';

export const proxyRequest = async (method, path, headers = {}, body = null, params = {}, config = {}) => {
  try {
    console.log('Method:', method);
      console.log('Path:', `${path.join('/')}/`);
      console.log('Body:', body);
      console.log('Query:', params);
      // console.log('config:', config);
      console.log('Full URL:', axiosInstance.defaults.baseURL + `${path.join('/')}/`);

    const response = await axiosInstance({
      method,
      url: `${path.join('/')}/`,
      headers,
      data: body,
      params,
      config:{
        ...config,
        isServerSide:true
      }
    });

    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle or throw the error based on your use case
    console.error('Proxy request failed:', error);
    return error.response.data;
    // throw error;
  }
};
```

middleware for client side requests
[...path].js

```
import axiosInstance from '../../../utils/axiosInstance'

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const { path, ...query } = req.query;

    try {
      const url = `${path.join('/')}/`;

      //Assuming all requests through this proxy are treated as client-side requests
      // This may vary based on your application's architecture and needs

      const response = await axiosInstance({
        method: req.method,
        url,
        // headers,
        headers: { ...req.headers, host: undefined }, // Forward headers, but remove 'host'
        data:req.body,
        params:query,
        config: { // Nest custom configuration inside `config`
          isServerSide: false, // Assuming this is always client-side in this context
      },
      });

      console.log('Method:', req.method);
      console.log('Path:', url);
      console.log('Body:', req.body);
      console.log('Query:', query);
      console.log('Full URL:', axiosInstance.defaults.baseURL + url);

      console.log(response.data)
      res.status(response.status).json(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(error.response?.status || 500).json(error.response?.data 
        // || { message: "An error occurred" }
        );
    }
  }
```

refresh token hook

```
export const refreshTokenHook = async (ctx = {}) => {
    try{
     console.log('TESTTTT token')

    console.log('Attempting token refresh');
        // Attempt to retrieve the refreshToken from cookies
        const { refreshToken } = parseCookies(ctx);
      
        console.log('refreshToken:', refreshToken);

        if (!refreshToken) {
            throw new Error('No refresh token available');
        }


      const result = await axios.get('/api/proxy/token/refresh',{refreshToken:refreshToken});

      console.log('Refresh result:', result.data);
      if (result.status === 200) {
          // Assuming the response includes the new access token
          storeAccessTokenInCookies(null, { access: result.data.access });
          return result.data.access; // Return the new access token
      } else {
          throw new Error('Failed to refresh token');
      }
      
    }catch (error) {
      console.error('Login hook error:', error.response?.data);
    }
  };
```

I have 2 problems

1. access token are not getting attached to my headers inside my interceptor, therefore fore each request i need to place it like this:

```
const response = await axios.get(`/api/proxy/product/${storeId}/`, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        });
```

2)for the refresh token hook, refresh token is always returned as undefined.

Comment: It would be easier to create a reproducible code base. There is alot of code here

Comment: @Yilmaz let me try to example it briefly until i create a code base. I am trying to implement axios interceptors in my nextjs web app. My problem is that my inside my interceptor i am not being able to attach the header with client side requests. for server side requests it is working.